# Dirichlet series associated to divisor function

Tags: dirichlet-series

How can I express the following Dirichlet series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d_{k}^{2}(n)}{n^{s}}$$ (where $d(n)$-divisor function;$k\geq 1$) in terms of the zeta function?

Comment: Cross-posted:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4351519/dirichlet-series-associated-to-divisor-function

Comment: You shouldn't crosspost so rapidly. First, wait for comments and answers on MSE.

Comment: See eq. (3.56) and (3.57) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4038 .

Comment: @R.J.Mathar: Why don't you post that as an answer? It seems exactly what the OP wants.